# Convert an iPad Playground to a Xcode 10 Playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swift-playground

New created Xcode 10 playgrounds are offering a play button to execute a playground step by step.

[image]

If I open a playground created on an iPad or in a previous versions of Xcode the play button is missing.

[image]

I would like to convert all my existing playgrounds to Xcode 10 style playgrounds but did not find any possibility to do so in a simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those playgrounds must be set to `Automatically Run`, it is unrelated to the device on which it was created/Xcode version.

The play button shows up when the playground is set to `Manually Run`

[image: Play button]

Comment: Thanks, perfect,. How could I oversee this.